# css : hamburger menu should scroll individually

Tags: jquery, html, css, hamburger-menu

Following is plunker link : http://plnkr.co/edit/peQEGK4mNiPBqlknrO6V?p=preview

when page loads hamburger menu should be closed and when we click on icon it should open and scroll individually.

I dont want to use hamburger.js . Without that how to achieve this functionality.

code :

```
 <div id="navBar">
<nav id="nav" class="side-nav">
    <!--<ul>
        <li><a href="#">menuitem 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">menuitem 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">menuitem 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">menuitem 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">menuitem 5</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">menuitem 6</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">menuitem 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">menuitem 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">menuitem 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">menuitem 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">menuitem 5</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">menuitem 6</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">menuitem 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">menuitem 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">menuitem 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">menuitem 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">menuitem 5</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">menuitem 6</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">menuitem 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">menuitem 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">menuitem 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">menuitem 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">menuitem 5</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">menuitem 6</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">menuitem 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">menuitem 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">menuitem 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">menuitem 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">menuitem 5</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">menuitem 6</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">menuitem 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">menuitem 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">menuitem 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">menuitem 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">menuitem 5</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">menuitem 6</a></li>-->
        <ul id="nav-contain" aria-live="polite" title="navigation menu" tabindex="-1">
     <li class="menu-home main-menu closed">
        <a href="#"  >
           <p >Menu Level 1</p>
        </a>

     </li>
     <li class="main-menu closed" >
        <a href="#" >
           <p>Menu Level 1</p>
        </a>

     </li>
     <li class="main-menu closed">
        <a href="#" >
           <p>Menu Level 1</p>
        </a>

     </li>
     <li class="main-menu closed" >
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" >
           <p>Menu</p>
        </a>
        <ul class="expand" >
           <li class="main-menu" >
              <a href="#">
                 <p>Menu</p>
              </a>

           </li>

  </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="main-menu closed">
        <a href="#" >
           <p>Menu Level 1</p>
        </a>

     </li>
     <li class="main-menu closed">
        <a href="#" >
           <p>Menu Level 1</p>
        </a>

     </li>
     <li class="main-menu closed">
        <a href="#" >
           <p>Menu Level 1</p>
        </a>

     </li>
     <li class="main-menu closed">
        <a href="#" >
           <p>Menu Level 1</p>
        </a>

     </li>
     <li class="main-menu closed">
        <a href="#" >
           <p>Menu Level 1</p>
        </a>

     </li>
     <li class="main-menu closed">
        <a href="#" >
           <p>Menu Level 1</p>
        </a>

     </li>
     <li class="main-menu closed">
        <a href="#" >
           <p>Menu Level 1</p>
        </a>

     </li>
     <li class="main-menu closed">
        <a href="#" >
           <p>Menu Level 1</p>
        </a>

     </li>
     <li class="main-menu closed">
        <a href="#" >
           <p>Menu Level 1</p>
        </a>

     </li>
  </ul>

</nav>
</div>
```

What is wrong in css.

Answer (score 0):

I created the library [**BlackTie.js**](https://github.com/divakarmanivel/blacktie), which does **exactly** what you need!

---

### How to use it

You can add a hamburger menu by adding this code inside your body tag :

```
<ul id="ham-menu">
    <li class="ham-item"><a href="#">Item one</a></li>
    <li class="ham-item"><a href="#">Item two</a></li>
    <li class="ham-item"><a href="#">Item three</a></li>
    <li class="ham-item"><a href="#">Item four</a></li>
</ul>
```

All other elements must come under the container div element below this ul tag :

```
<div id="container">
    ...
    //app body content goes here
    ...
</div>
```

For more info, see [**the official documentation**](https://github.com/divakarmanivel/blacktie).